# JGroups protocols for synchronous RPC calls

Tags: java, cluster-computing, rpc, jgroups

Our cluster of ~50 members uses JGroups for 1-2-1 RPC calls (synchronous).

*Tens of thousands of calls are made in a day, which complete in the range of 10 ms to 1 hour. Request & response size are ranging from 0 to 100 MB.*

Our hosts are scattered in different data centres, hence TCP is used.

There are **no multi-cast messages, only synchronous RPC calls.**

What all protocols from conf/tcp.xml should be used with latest JGroups version?
Is there anything better than TCP Like TCP_NIO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which complete in the range of 10 ms to 1 hour.

If an RPC can take up to 1 hour, I don't think *synchronous* RPCs are the way to go; I'd rather suggest to switch to async ones... Alternatively, you could invoke RPCs which return a CompletableFuture, whose function is called whenever the call has completed. This has the advantage that you're not blocking a thread from the pool...

I'd start out with `tcp.xml` and make changes as needed. E.g. increase the max_threads variable to 50, to accommodate all 50 members sendind at the same time.

Also, think about whether to use regular or OOB RPCs: unless you need ordering, OOB RPCs can be delivered in parallel, whereas regular RPCs (by the same sender) aer delivered one-by-one.

If you don't need state transfer, remove `BARRIER` and `STATE_TRANSFER`.

I suggest write a simple perf test (or use UPerf) and measure whether the perf is suitable. I'd also use `probe.sh` to take a look at stats.

You can tune so many things in JGroups, it would take too long to list all measures here...

[1] http://www.jgroups.org/manual4/index.html#RpcDispatcher

Comment: Thanks Bela! What happens if RPC call is taking an hour, and network partition occurs after 30 minutes, does application need to handle this situation? Will RPC call still be completed without any issues ?

Comment: If the RPC is unicast (= to 1 destination) and that destination is on the same side of the partition, then nothing happens. If it is on the other side, the call will terminate with a SuspectException. If this is a one-to-many RPC, then the members on the other side will be flagged as suspected, but the call will not return until we have received responses from all non-suspected members.

Comment: Unless it silently fails or stucks forever, it would serve my purpose. A long full GC on coordinator has any impact? Also I'm planning to use File_Ping using a MapR file system, hopefully it would be stable.

Comment: A GC would delay a response, but eventually, if the GC is longer than the failure detection timeout, that member would also get suspected and excluded from the response set. Note that you can bound the max time of RPCs with timeouts...

Comment: FILE_PING is a very simple discovery protocol, but I haven't seen it being used a lot in production...

Comment: Few members restart every day, and sometimes new machines are added in the cluster. Currently we are using TCPPING, I thought FILE_PING would be a good candidate. Would you suggest anything else?

Comment: Thanks for your help Bela, much appreciated!